# User licensing for Remote Desktop Connections on Azure VMs

Tags: azure, licensing

I have one VM on Azure running Windows Server 2016 that will act as a Terminal Server.  I can make a Remote Desktop Connection to the box but when one more user tries, it kicks off the first connection.  I have read conflicting articles and posts on an initial limit of users with licensing.  I have also read conflicting articles on which licensing is needed.  Some of the articles are dated.  In 2021, what do I need for several users to connect to this VM?  And where do I purchase licenses if I need them?

Thank you very much,
Phillip

Comment: You need RDS CAL's to access a RDSH server in Azure or on premises. This requirement has not changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @joeqwerty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no license to allow multiple sessions. For that you need Server and RDS licenses.
For multiple users to connect to the same system, you will need to run a server OS with RDS enabled (requires additional licensing). Otherwise, you should run a separate PC per user to remote.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server supports the use of remote desktop without a licence for Remote Administration only. If you are using it as a terminal server you will need to purchase RDS CAL's. These can be purchased from any Microsoft reseller.

Comment: Sam, thanks as always for your reply.  Being this is a TS on Azure, do I need SALs or CALs?

Comment: If it is just internal users then it may just be CAL's but you probably need to get MS licencing to confirm

Comment: OK thanks I'm checking with the reseller.

Comment: I'm being told Azure requires Software Assurance also.  Is this true?

Comment: You would need to check with your licencing rep or Microsoft